# make fatal error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, make, openssl, ssl

I'm trying to compile a program that, according to the documentation, requires the "OpenSSL library". I have OpenSSL installed, and it's still giving me the error `openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory`. Is there some other library that has to be installed?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

probably you are missing the openssl header files. depending on your distribution this package might have a different name, mostly it's something like `openssl-dev` or `openssl-devel`. after you installed the openssl header files, the compiler should be able to find openssl/sha.h.

In Ubuntu/Debian the package is called `libssl-dev`.

Comment: Turns out it was "libcurl4-openssl-dev". Not sure what libcurl has do do with SSL or SHA256, but it worked.

Comment: @tkbx `/usr/include/openssl/sha.h` is in [`libssl-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/libssl-dev) in oldstable, stable and unstable.

Comment: FYI: I already had `libcurl4-openssl-dev` installed. `libssl-dev` sorted this for me.